# How to solve BadZipFile: File is not a zip file error in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to read .xlsx files from folders in a specific directory and to write/export them into 4 new .xlsx files, which every new .xlsx will be containing data catalog per year.
The script works well when i tried it some months ago but it's not working anymore. It keeps on resulting BadZipFile: File is not a zip file error.

Do I miss something? I've tried upgrading and downgrading the anaconda, python, openpyxl, and pandas version but it doesn't help.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

path_folder = r'C:\\Users\\lala\\Downloads\\New folder\\Data Klimatologi\\'
folder_tahun = os.listdir(path_folder)

year_folder

for x in year_folder:
    year_folder = os.listdir(path_folder + x)
    frames = []
    for y in station_folder:
        path_file = path_folder + '{}\\{}'.format(x,y)
        files = os.listdir(path_file)
        for z in files:
            pattern = path_folder + '{}\\{}\\{}'.format(x,y,z)
            wb = load_workbook(filename = pattern)
            sheet = wb.active#has 1 sheet
            max_row_for_Tn = max((b.row for b in sheet['B'] if b.value is not None))
            cell = 'A9:K%d' % (max_row_for_Tn)
            data = sheet[cell]
            row_list = []
            for row in data:
                cols = []
                for col in row:
                    cols.append(col.value)
                row_list.append(cols)
            df = pd.DataFrame(data = row_list[1:], index=None, columns=row_list[0])
            cell_id = sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 3)
            pk = cell_id.value
            pk = re.sub('[\s]+', '', pk)
            pk = int(re.sub(r'[^.,a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]','', pk))
            df['Id WMO'] = pk
            frames.append(df)
    result = pd.concat(frames)
    result.to_excel(r'C:\Users\lala\OneDrive\Documents\Dataset\Dataset Stasiun BMKG Tahun {}.xlsx'.format(x), index = False)
```

The script works well until `year_folder` giving the output ('2000','2001','2002','2003','2004').

Here's the traceback.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-e8e2d94d1368> in <module>
      7         for z in files:
      8             pattern = path_folder + '{}\\{}\\{}'.format(x,y,z)
----> 9             wb = load_workbook(filename = pattern)
     10             sheet = wb.active#has 1 sheet
     11             max_row_for_Tn = max((b.row for b in sheet['B'] if b.value is not None))

~\anaconda3\envs\Pandas\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    312     """
    313     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
--> 314                         data_only, keep_links)
    315     reader.read()
    316     return reader.wb

~\anaconda3\envs\Pandas\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in __init__(self, fn, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    122     def __init__(self,  fn, read_only=False, keep_vba=KEEP_VBA,
    123                   data_only=False, keep_links=True):
--> 124         self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
    125         self.valid_files = self.archive.namelist()
    126         self.read_only = read_only

~\anaconda3\envs\Pandas\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in _validate_archive(filename)
     94             raise InvalidFileException(msg)
     95 
---> 96     archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
     97     return archive
     98 

~\anaconda3\envs\Pandas\lib\zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64)
   1129         try:
   1130             if mode == 'r':
-> 1131                 self._RealGetContents()
   1132             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1133                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

~\anaconda3\envs\Pandas\lib\zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1196             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1197         if not endrec:
-> 1198             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1199         if self.debug > 1:
   1200             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: Will you please add the full traceback for the error message to the question?

Comment: @user17242583 Thank you for asking. Now I have added the full traceback

Answer (score 0):

The error message is exactly correct.  Current versions of Excel use the `.xlsx` format, which are zip files containing a small directory tree.  That format was not introduced until Excel 2007.  Assuming those files really are from 2001, 2002, etc., they are in the old-style Excel `.xls` format, which is not a zip file.  `pandas` does not know how to import `.xls` files.  You may need to find a separate module to convert them.

Comment: i've checked them and all of the files are in .xlsx format. could it be because of corrupted files? i can access all the files manually but i dont know if (perhaps) there are some files that python cant read

Comment: It's possible.  Can you open them with Excel?  Is it possible you have `.xls` files that someone renamed to `.xlsx`?

Comment: yes i can open them all with Excel. I downloaded the data from an official web and they were all already .xlsx files

Answer (score 0):

It turned out one of the `.xlsx` file was duplicated. I deleted the duplicated file and the error isn't showing up anymore.
If anyone find the same error, you can check them separately if there's corrupted/doubled files in your directory.
It won't be a problem to use the same file name as long as the files contain different values in it.